# Using dplyr to create vector of unique combinations of values for a given group

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset where each row contains an event identifier and columns contain information on an invitee and an organizer.  Multiple rows will have the same event identifier.  I want to aggregate over the event identifier, generating a list of unique invitees and organizers.

Let's say I have the following dataset:

```
test <- data.frame(id = stringi::stri_rand_strings(100, 1, '[A-Z]'), invitee_id = floor(runif(100, min=0, max=500)), organizer_id = floor(runif(100, min=0, max=500)))
```

I want to group_by the 'id' variable, and create a new column that is a comma-delimited vector of all the unique values of invitee_id and organizer_id.  The end result for the first row may look like:

```
> final_df
    id invitee_id organizer_id unique_vals
1    L        481          396 (481, 396, 300, 100, 200)
```

Where we have collapsed on final_df.

I attempted something like:

```
final_df <- test %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  distinct(invitee_id, .keep_all=TRUE)
```

The end goal is an adjacency matrix where rows and columns are the IDs of attendees and the values represent the number of shared events.

More clear example:

Let's say I have this test data

```
> test
   id invitee_id organizer_id
1   A        478          444
2   A        226          346
3   A        338          320
4   A        286          497
5   B        478          327
6   B        226          354
7   B        123          272
8   C        226          297
9   C        338          144
10  C        477           73
```

I'm trying to group_by id and aggregate across invitee and organizers like so:

```
> final_df
   id invitee_id_merged   organizer_id_merged  grouped_values
1   A  c(478, 226, 338)   c(444, 346, 320)     c(478, 226, 338, 444, 346, 320)
```

The end goal is an adjacency matrix where a unique list of both invitees and organizer IDs represent the rows and columns.  The values of a given row, column should represent the number of times those two individuals met in an event.  So the first row would look like this:

```
> final_matrix
invitee_or_organizer

    478 226 338 286 123 477 ...
478 2
226 1
338 1
286 1
123 0
477 0 
 ...
```

Comment: Because you didn't have a set.seed, it is hard to know what the expected output is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After grouping by 'id', we can `summarise` to concatenate all the `unique` elements of both columns

```
test %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise_all(funs(toString(unique(.))))
```

---

Another option is to store the `unique` elements as `list`

```
library(tidyverse)
test %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise_all(funs(merged = list(unique(.)))) %>%
  mutate(grouped_values = map2(invitee_id_merged, organizer_id_merged, c))
```

---

Also, based on the description if the end result is the frequency count in a adjacency dataset

```
test %>% 
   count(invitee_id, organizer_id) %>%
   spread(organizer_id, n, fill = 0)
```

#### Update

Based on the edit in the OP's post,

```
crossprod(table(rep(test$id, 2), unlist(test[-1])))
```

Comment: This is fantastic! One quick comment -- the values in the adjacency dataset should represent how many times a specific combination of invitees were at the same event. It looks like your code computes the number of times an invitee and an organizer were at the same event, bit I'm not sure what the spreading command is doing.

Comment: @Parseltongue  Thanks, it is not clear to me.  If you can change your example with a `set.seed` and the expected output for few lines, it would be helpful

Comment: Sorry for being imprecise!  And thanks again.  I threw up a hard-coded example that might be more clear. @akrun

Comment: @Parseltongue  No problem.  Please check the updated code in my post

Comment: is there any chance you can explain the crossprod code?  I've been puzzling over it for days. @akrun

Comment: @Parseltongue  If you split the code, the `unlist(test[-1])` converts the data.frame without the 'id' column into a `vector`, inorder to keep the length the same, replicate the 'id' column twice as the number of columns minus the 'id' is 2.  `table` gives the frequency of 'id' with the other columns in a matrix `tbl <- table(rep(test$id, 2), unlist(test[-1]))`.  `t*tbl) %*% tbl` gives the same output as `crossprod(tbl)` or `crossprod(tbl, tbl)` In the documentation, `?crossprod`, `x, y: numeric or complex matrices (or vectors): ‘y = NULL’ is taken
          to be the same matrix as ‘x’.`

Comment: Thanks so much.  Makes a lot more sense now. One issue is that, when I try to use the table command on my actual data, I get the following error: `"Error in table(rep(calendar_team$meeting_id, 2), unlist(calendar_team[,  : 
  attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements"` . I can use the code suggested by Vlad to make the adjacency dataframe, but I'm having trouble converting a dataframe to an edgelist because it's not a square matrix due to the addition of a named column.  I know I've taken up a lot of your time already, so feel free to ignore.  In any case, thanks a lot for all your help

Comment: @Parseltongue  the length exceeds that limit and that is the reason for the error.  Not sure if the reshaping helps in that case

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like a dataframe where both the columns and the rows are given by a union of `invitee_id` and `organizer_id` and the values would be the distinct counts of events where they both participated in, this should be a way to accomplish that:

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)

test %>%
  melt('id', value.name = 'person_id') %>%
  dcast(person_id~person_id, fun.aggregate = n_distinct, value.var = 'id')
```