# Is there a solution in R to generate unique combinations and their frequency?

Tags: r

Here is my code. I am trying to generate all non-repeating combinations of the Food column and how many times it appears given the ID column.

```
customerDataFrame <- data.frame(CustomerID = c('A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'D'),
                                Food = c('Pizza', 'Pizza', 'Tacos', 'Tacos', 'Tacos', 'Pizza'))

customerDataFrame %>% 
  group_by(CustomerID) %>% 
  summarise_all(funs(toString(unique(.)))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(Food) %>%
  summarise(n= n())
```

Here is the output right now:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  Food             n
  <chr>        <int>
1 Pizza            1
2 Pizza, Tacos     1
3 Tacos            1
4 Tacos, Pizza     1
```

This is technically incorrect because the customers who purchase (Pizza, Tacos) and (Tacos, Pizza) should be in the same group. It doesn't matter what order they purchase in.

(I got the code from this answer: [Using dplyr to create vector of unique combinations of values for a given group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51467203/using-dplyr-to-create-vector-of-unique-combinations-of-values-for-a-given-group))

Here is what I am trying to get:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  Food             n
  <chr>        <int>
1 Pizza            1
2 Pizza, Tacos     2
3 Tacos            1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. You can double `summarise()` in order to get the expected result:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
new <- customerDataFrame %>%
  arrange(CustomerID,Food)%>%
  group_by(CustomerID) %>%
  summarise(Food=paste0(Food,collapse = ',')) %>%
  group_by(Food,.drop = T) %>%
  summarise(N=n())
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Food            N
  <chr>       <int>
1 Pizza           1
2 Pizza,Tacos     2
3 Tacos           1
```

The same output can be reached using `toString()`:

```
#Code 2
new <- customerDataFrame %>%
  arrange(CustomerID,Food)%>%
  group_by(CustomerID) %>%
  summarise(Food=toString(Food)) %>%
  group_by(Food,.drop = T) %>%
  summarise(N=n())
```

Answer (score 3):

When you are collapsing using `toString` `sort` the `Food`.

```
library(dplyr)

customerDataFrame %>% 
  group_by(CustomerID) %>% 
  summarise(Food = toString(sort(Food))) %>%
  count(Food)

#   Food            n
#  <chr>        <int>
#1 Pizza            1
#2 Pizza, Tacos     2
#3 Tacos            1
```

Answer (score 0):

In `base R`, we can use `table` with `aggregate`

```
table(aggregate(Food ~ CustomerID, 
   customerDataFrame[do.call(order, customerDataFrame),], FUN = toString)$Food)

#  Pizza Pizza, Tacos        Tacos 
#      1            2            1
```